# Youtube Embed not loading on SSL. Wordpress cause of error?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, youtube

I have a WordPress plugin which displays embedded youtube videos. It worked before I moved my site to SSL. Now I'm getting this message in chrome

....was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/DU2iwGYtprI?rel=0&wmode=transparent'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Chrome also  points to the included wordpress jQuery file
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4

I tried using a mixed content fixer but that didn't seem to help at all.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: You have to specify all links to YouTube video with https://